# Aggregation query using Mongo repository

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo repository in my project. I need to use aggregation framework of mongodb, but i am unable to find any helping doc about how to use aggregation query using mongo repository.

I am using simple queries using mongo repository like this

```
@Repository
public interface TaskTypeMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<TaskType,String>{

    @Query(value="{ 'subServiceId' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'title' : 1, 'description' : 1,'expiresOn':1,'taskTypeStatus':1}")
    List <TaskType> findBySubService(Long subServiceId);

    @Query(fields="{ 'title' : 1, 'description' : 1,'expiresOn':1,'taskTypeStatus':1}")
    List<TaskType> findByOrganizationId(long organizationId);

    List <TaskType> findByIdIn(List<String> taskTypeIds);

    TaskType findById(String id);
}
```

I have to use this aggregation query

```
db.task_packages.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$taskTypeIds"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "taskType",
            localField: "taskTypeIds",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "task_types"
        }
   },
{ "$unwind": "$task_types" },
{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
       "packageName":{"$first":"$packageName"},
       "task_names": { "$push": "$task_types.title" }
        }
    },
{
        "$project": {
            "packageName": 1,  
            "task_names" : 1
        }
    }
])
```

I have used aggregation query by using template method, but don't now how to use with repository ?

Comment: Please also add the sample document to the post n also add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean the collection sample that you are trying to write the query for. It will help test testing the answer. did you already implemented the query using mongo template ?

Comment: Yes i have used with mongo template.

Comment: Okay then we just have to provide a custom method in repository, inject mongo template and use that to return reaponse from the repository method.